# Stopping the ding sound when using MessageDlg in the OnCloseQuery event

Tags: delphi, messagebox

I found Users were inadvertently poking the main form's system menu "X" and closing the program.

To alleviate the problem, I added code to ask the User if they were sure they wanted to close the program. Doing this solved people doing high stress event check-in from having to get help relaunching the program. A win all the way around for this program.

However, there is an annoying Ding sound whenever I use MessageDlg function in the OnCloseQuery event of the main form.

Using Delphi 10.4 Professional

File->New->"Windows VCL Application - Delphi"
Place the following code in the OnCloseQuery Event

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  iOkToClose: integer;
begin
  iOkToClose
    := MessageDlg('Do you wish to close the DertSQL program?',
                  mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0, mbNo);
  if iOkToClose <> mrYes then
    CanClose := FALSE
  else CanClose := TRUE;
end;
```

Compile and run the program then poke the system menu "X"

Question: How do I get rid of the Ding sound caused by the MessageDlg function?

Comment: Is it annoying for your users, too, or just for you? In the latter case consider [disabling Windows system sounds](https://superuser.com/q/134315/650342) entirely - those were never a help to me, always a nuisance. Otherwise don't force your preferences onto all users at once (maybe a couple of them expect the sound and would be puzzled to not hear it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's just note that your code

```pascal
if iOkToClose <> mrYes then
  CanClose := False
else
  CanClose := True
```

is much better written as

```pascal
CanClose := iOkToClose = mrYes
```

In fact, you don't even need the variable. Your entire event handler can be written simply

```pascal
CanClose :=
  MessageDlg(
    'Do you wish to close the DertSQL program?',
    mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0, mbNo
  ) = mrYes;
```

---

Now, the beep you hear is associated with the icon, so one way to get rid of the beep is to remove the icon:

```pascal
CanClose :=
  MessageDlg(
    'Do you wish to close the DertSQL program?',
    TMsgDlgType.mtCustom, [mbYes, mbNo], 0, mbNo
  ) = mrYes;
```

Also, there are many ways to display a message box in the VCL.

You are currently using the `MessageDlg` function, which I personally am not hugely fond of.

One alternative is the standard Win32 `MessageBox` function:

```pascal
CanClose :=
  MessageBox(
    Handle,
    'Do you want to close this application?',
    'My App',
    MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO
  ) = ID_YES;
```

Here there's no beep.

But it is even better to use the task dialog:

```pascal
var dlg := TTaskDialog.Create(Self);
try
  dlg.Caption := 'My App';
  dlg.Title := 'Do you want to exit the application?';
  dlg.MainIcon := tdiNone;
  dlg.CommonButtons := [tcbYes, tcbNo];
  CanClose := dlg.Execute and (dlg.ModalResult = mrYes);
finally
  dlg.Free;
end;
```

This is particularly nice because you then follow the Win32 UI guidelines with a blue, main instruction:

[image: Screenshot of confirmation task dialog]

But as you can see, this is a lot of code. You probably want to make your own message dialog function based on the task dialog, like I do in my [Task Dialog Message Box](https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/TDMessageBox/TDMessageBox.html):

```pascal
CanClose := TD('Do you want to exit the application?')
  .YesNo
  .Execute(Self) = mrYes;
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Recall that Microsoft deprecated the question icon a few years ago. You should *not* use a question mark icon in a "confirmation" dialog. The TD approach uses no icon, as you can see, in accordance with the Win32 UI guidelines. The OP's `mtConfirmation`, however, produces an information icon (not a question mark icon!), and so you get that icon's sound.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Vcl.Dialogs.pas:6861: `const IconMap: array[TMsgDlgType] of TTaskDialogIcon = (tdiWarning, tdiError,
    tdiInformation, tdiInformation, tdiNone);`